# KafkaRebalancer handle with Spring Configurations

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using spring-kafka (1.3.2.RELEASE) in our application.
Right now we are using auto-commit=true in our configurations.
We faced some problem because of same, like same offset getting read multiple times, so we are now planning to do manual commits and possibly save the read offsets in some external repository.

We need to handle kafka rebalances as well.
I have read the documentation, in plain java, rebalance listener is configured using ContainerProperties.
setConsumerRebalanceListener(rebalanceListner);

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#_very_very_quick

I am searching for configuring Rebalance listneres using Spring Java Configurations, but unable to find one. 
Kindly let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have something like this:

```
@Bean
ContainerProperties containerProperties() {
   ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(SOME_TOPIC);
   containerProperties.setConsumerRebalanceListener(myConsumerRebalanceListener());
   // Other properties set
   return containerProperties;
}

@Bean
ConsumerRebalanceListener myConsumerRebalanceListener() {
   return new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {

            }
   }
}
```

That `containerProperties` bean you can use in the `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` instance or you can populate that `myConsumerRebalanceListener` in the `AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties()`.